# UIToolbar in UINaviationItem weird line at the top

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to display a UIToolbar in UINavigationItem's titleView via:

```
UIBarButtonItem *mapItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"world_icon"]
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                           target:self action:@selector(hi)];
UIBarButtonItem *mapItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"world_icon"]
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                           target:self action:@selector(hi)];
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[toolbar setItems:@[mapItem, spaceItem, mapItem2, spaceItem]];
toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
              forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.navigationItem.titleView = toolbar;
```

But I am getting this weird black line at the top of the toolbar:

[image]

Any ideas what's causing this? Thanks!

Comment: did you close down your simulator and restarted your xcode and still face the same issue?

Comment: add border of your toolbar and set that border color is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know way this happening, but I had same issue like a yours and I fixed it as use

```
toolbar.clipsToBounds = YES
```

Also you can try with following
**OR**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]
                                  forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```